# xamarin android fragments overlapping

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, xamarin.android, android-fragmentactivity

I know there are a lot of questions already discussing this issue but I still can't figure out what is wrong with my implementation.

I'm using a SherlockFragmentActivity with ActionBar that has 4 tabs, each tab fills the FrameLayout with a different Fragment.

Up to here I have no problem, the tabs switch between fragments perfectly.

But on Tab "Buy" when the searchButton is clicked I replace the FrameLayout with another ListFragment using the Activity1 NavigateTo method, which results in overlapping the current Fragment and won't disappear no matter what I do from this point.

Please advise, I have read all the solution and can't find the problem, let me know if another part of the code is required

Here is my code:
Activity1:

```
public class Activity1 : SherlockFragmentActivity, ActionBar_Sherlock.App.ActionBar.ITabListener
    {
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            userid = 2;

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
            SupportActionBar.NavigationMode = (int)ActionBarNavigationMode.Tabs;
            SupportActionBar.SetDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
            //Set the mobile service Sale table adapter
            //this.adapter = new SalesAdapter(this.MobileServiceContext.SaleTable, Resource.Layout.OffersListItem, this);

            //Initialize tabs
            Tab tab = SupportActionBar.NewTab();
            tab.SetTag("MyProfile");
            tab.SetText("My Profile");
            tab.SetTabListener(this);
            SupportActionBar.AddTab(tab);

            tab = SupportActionBar.NewTab();
            tab.SetTag("Buy");
            tab.SetText("Buy");
            tab.SetTabListener(this);
            SupportActionBar.AddTab(tab);

            tab = SupportActionBar.NewTab();
            tab.SetTag("Sell");
            tab.SetText("Sell");
            tab.SetTabListener(this);
            SupportActionBar.AddTab(tab);

            tab = SupportActionBar.NewTab();
            tab.SetTag("Rates");
            tab.SetText("Rates");
            tab.SetTabListener(this);
            SupportActionBar.AddTab(tab);

        }

        public void OnTabSelected(Tab tab, Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentTransaction ft)
        {
            string tag = tab.Tag.ToString();

            Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment f = SupportFragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag(tag);
            if (f != null)
            {
                ft.Show(f);
                return;
            }

            if (tag == "MyProfile")
                f = new Fragments.MyProfileFragment();
            else if (tag == "Buy")
                f = new Fragments.BuyFragment();
            else if (tag == "Sell")
                f = new Fragments.SaleFragment();
            else if (tag == "Rates")
                f = new Fragments.BuyFragment();



            ft.Add(Resource.Id.fragmentContainer, f, tag);
        }


        public void OnTabUnselected(Tab tab, Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentTransaction ft)
        {
            string tag = tab.Tag.ToString();

            Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment f = SupportFragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag(tag);
            if (f != null)
            {
                ft.Hide(f);
                return;
            }
        }

        public void OnTabReselected(Tab tab, Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentTransaction ft)
        {
            //Do nothing
        }

        public void NavigateTo(Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment newFragment)
        {
            Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentManager manager = SupportFragmentManager;
            Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentTransaction ft = manager.BeginTransaction();

            ft.Replace(Resource.Id.fragmentContainer, newFragment);
            ft.SetTransition((int)FragmentTransit.FragmentFade);
            // Add this trnasaction to the back stack, so when the user press back,
            // it rollbacks.
            ft.AddToBackStack(null);
            ft.Commit();
        }

        public override void OnBackPressed()
        {
            Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentManager manager = SupportFragmentManager;
            if (manager.BackStackEntryCount > 0)
            {
                base.OnBackPressed();
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
}
```

This is the Main layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <FrameLayout
      android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dip"
      android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the BuyFragment:

```
public class BuyFragment : Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment
    {
        private Activity1 myActivity;
        private string currency;
        private int amount;
        private EditText buyAmount;
        private Button searchButton;
        private Spinner currencySpinner;

        public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            myActivity = (Activity1)this.Activity;
        }

        public override void OnActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            //Init the currency spinner
            currencySpinner = this.Activity.FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.spinnerBuy);
            myActivity.InitCurrencySpinner(currencySpinner);

            //Parse the amount text to int
            buyAmount = this.Activity.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.buyEdittext);
            buyAmount.AfterTextChanged += (sender, args) =>
            {
                //
                int result;
                int.TryParse(buyAmount.Text, out result);

                amount = result;
            };

            searchButton = this.Activity.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.buyButton);
            searchButton.Click += (sender, e) =>
            {
                OnClickSearch(sender, e);
            };

            //Disable all buttons if the adapter is updating
            myActivity.SalesAdapter.IsUpdatingChanged += (s, e) =>
            {
                this.buyAmount.Enabled =
                this.currencySpinner.Enabled =
                this.searchButton.Enabled =
                    !myActivity.SalesAdapter.IsUpdating;
            };
        }

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle bundle)
        {
            return inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.BuyLayout, container, false);
        }

        private void OnClickSearch(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            try
            {
                if (amount > 0)
                {
                    currency = currencySpinner.SelectedItem.ToString();
                    SearchOffers();
                    this.buyAmount.Text = null;
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.MakeText(this.Activity, "Amount must be a number larger than 0", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SaleFragment.OnClickPutForSale: {0} Exception caught.", e.InnerException);
            }
        }

        private void SearchOffers()
        {
            //Check what fragment is shown, replace if needed.
            var fragmentContainer = FragmentManager.FindFragmentById(Resource.Id.fragmentContainer) as SearchListFragment;
            if (fragmentContainer == null)
            {
                // Make new fragment to show this selection.
                fragmentContainer = SearchListFragment.NewInstance(amount, currency);

                // Execute a transaction, replacing any existing
                // fragment with this one inside the frame.
                myActivity.NavigateTo(fragmentContainer);
            }
            //else
            //{
            //    fragmentContainer.Arguments.PutString("currency", currency);
            //    fragmentContainer.Arguments.PutInt("amount", amount);
            //    myActivity.NavigateTo(fragmentContainer);
            //}
        }
```

Buy layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:text="@string/currency_prompt"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerBuy"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:prompt="@string/currency_prompt"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10.0dp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:text="@string/amount_prompt"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/buyEdittext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:inputType="number" />
    <Button
        android:text="@string/BuyButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/buyButton"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I have a similar problem, as you do.
Which version of ActionBarSherlock do you use?

Comment: @balint I don't know, how do I check?

Comment: @balint I'm using the latest 4.3.1 version

Comment: @NirSchachter have you found a solution ? I encounter the same problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace:

```
ft.Add(Resource.Id.fragmentContainer, f, tag);
```

With:

```
ft.Replace(Resource.Id.fragmentContainer, f, tag);
```